# Jenkins Views: Only show jobs that have had successful builds in the last 30 days

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to create a view in Jenkins that will only show jobs that have had a successful build in the last 30 days (Last Success <= 30 days)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible with the 'View Job Filters' plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/view-job-filters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Job Filter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/view-job-filters/) to filter based on your criteria. There is a neat explanation from [CloudBees blog](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/controlling-what-you-see-view-job-filters-jenkins-plugin) on this.